# Surjectivity in little diagram

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

Given the following commutative diagram of exact sequences

$$
\begin{array}
& & 0 & 0 & 0  &\\
& \downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow  &\\
 0 \rightarrow & A \stackrel{u}\rightarrow & B \stackrel{v}\rightarrow & C \rightarrow & 0\\ 
& \downarrow f & \downarrow g & \downarrow h &\\
0 \rightarrow & A_1 \stackrel{u_1}\rightarrow & B_1 \stackrel{v_1}\rightarrow & C_1 & \\ 
& \downarrow & \downarrow g_1 & \downarrow h_1 &\\
& 0 \rightarrow & B_2 \stackrel{v_2}\rightarrow & C_2 \rightarrow & 0\\ 
\end{array}
$$

can I conclude that also $B_1\rightarrow C_1$ is surjective??

Comment: When diagram chasing doesn't work, then you should look for a counterexample.

Answer (score 3):

The following is a counterexample:
\begin{array}[ccccccccc]
\ & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & \\
 & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \\
0 & \rightarrow & 0 & \rightarrow & 0 & \rightarrow & 0 & \rightarrow & 0\\
 & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \\
0 & \rightarrow & 0 & \rightarrow & 0 & \rightarrow & \mathbb Z & & \\
 & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \\
 & & 0 & \rightarrow & \mathbb Z & \rightarrow & \mathbb Z & \rightarrow & 0\\
\end{array}